# follow button with a dot in user name

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to add a follow-up to my webpage:

Since my username has a dot, the button is not shown.
If I enter another usernme (without dot), it works.

Answer (score 0):

Should work with the numeric user id as well – if I go to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/follow/ and replace the URL `https://www.facebook.com/zuck` with `https://www.facebook.com/4`, then the plugin reloads correctly and still shows followers for Mark Zuckerberg.